# Split 2 column csv String in custom Arraylist

Tags: java, android, sqlite, csv, arraylist

I am having the following string in the sqlite database cell

```
1492972200000, 67.529999
1492367400000, 66.400002
1491762600000, 64.949997
1491157800000, 65.68
1490553000000, 65.860001
1489948200000, 64.980003
1489343400000, 64.870003
1488738600000, 64.93
1488133800000, 64.25
1487615400000, 64.620003
1486924200000, 64.620003
1486319400000, 64.00
1485714600000, 63.68
1485109800000, 65.779999
1484591400000, 62.740002
1483900200000, 62.700001
1483381800000, 62.84
1482777000000, 62.139999
1482085800000, 63.240002
1481481000000, 62.299999
1480876200000, 61.970001
1480271400000, 59.25
1479666600000, 60.529999
1479061800000, 60.349998
1478457000000, 59.02
1477852200000, 58.709999
1477247400000, 59.869999
1476642600000, 59.66
```

I want to split these in custom Arraylist with "time" and "value"

```
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String dataColumn = cursor.getString(Contract.Quote.POSITION_HISTORY);
                Timber.d(dataColumn);
//Timber.d is giving me the value above


            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
```

...

plus can someone tell me what factors show the simple notepad in this format
http://prntscr.com/f0ua6l

and notepad++ and android studio logger in this format 
http://prntscr.com/f0uag4

it may help in making the regex

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say create a  simple POJO class

```
class MyClass {
    private Date time;
    private Double value;

    public MyClass(String record) {
        values = record.split(',');
        time = new Date(new Long(values[0]));
        value = new Date(new Double(values[1]));
    }
    //Getters and setters for above    
}
```

Then you code can parse every record and create new objects for them and add to the array list. This how most of the ORM systems work.

```
ArrayList<MyClass> myList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
     do {
            String dataColumn = cursor.getString(Contract.Quote.POSITION_HISTORY);
            myObj = new MyClass(dataColumn);
            myList.append(myObj);


        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();

    //myList holds the list of items you want.
    //This way adding new field in DB can be managed easily. 
    //Separation of concern - basic principle in OO design
}
```

Hope it helps!